# Three20: Extracting NSArray from userinfo

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

I have been using Grinich's method of using the userinfo category for passing on objects, in which case I'm passing an array of FeedItem class objects. However, modelItems as well as feedItems return a null even when myPassedObject is able to print my items when i NSLog it.

```
 id myPassedObject = [query objectForKey:@"__userInfo__"];

    NSArray *modelItems = myPassedObject;

    for (FeedItem *feedItem in modelItems) {

     [feedItems addObject:feedItem];   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting `myPassedObject` to an NSArray when you assign it to `modelItems`. Doesn't seem to be anything else wrong.

Comment: He is doing this in the second line.

Comment: I just checked, I am able to pass over an individual object over just fine but the problem starts when i pass over an array of my objects. Something should be wrong with the way I'm casting that I haven't figured out.

Comment: use NSArray *modelItems = (NSArray *) myPassedObject;

Answer (score 0):

I would print out or inspect the query dictionary to ensure that you are passing myPassedObject in correctly.